# R loop to calculate date intervals

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe (customer) that looks like this:

```
    email    order_no  date       
a@stack.com  0012      2014-02-13  
a@stack.com  0013      2014-03-13  
a@stack.com  0014      2014-06-13  
b@stack.com  0015      2014-05-13   
b@stack.com  0016      2014-05-20  
b@stack.com  0017      2014-07-20
```

I want to create a new field that appends the interval between orders for each customer. The first step would be to order by date ascending:

`customer <- arrange(customer, date)`

The next step would be to iterate through each customer and calculate the order interval so the result set looks like this:

```
    email    order_no  date         days_interval
a@stack.com  0012      2014-02-13    0
a@stack.com  0013      2014-03-13    30
a@stack.com  0014      2014-06-13    90
b@stack.com  0015      2014-05-13    0 
b@stack.com  0016      2014-05-20    7
b@stack.com  0017      2014-07-20    60
```

Can this be achieved without using a for loop?
What's the most efficient way of doing this.

With a FOR Loop, this is what you do:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(customer)){
  if(customer$email[i]==customer$email[i-1]){
    customer$interval[i] <- as.integer(difftime(customer$date[i],customer$date[i-1]))
  }
}
```

Is this feasible without using a for loop?

Comment: the two data frames don't match. e.g., order `0016` is `2014-06-13` in the top data frame and `2014-05-20` in the bottom.

Comment: my mistake. Making update

Answer (score 0):

diff should work for you. It takes a vector of length n and returns a vector of length n-1 with the differences between the vector's items. Below is an example.

```
> data <- data.frame(name=c("jeff","steve","jim"),date=today()+seq(-3:-5))
> data
   name       date
1  jeff 2015-04-28
2 steve 2015-04-29
3   jim 2015-04-30
> diff(data$date)
Time differences in days
[1] 1 1
```

You just need to combine this with your current work. Such as with

```
customer$days_interval <- c(0, diff(customer$date))
```

Comment: Thank you. This however does not solve my problem and forgive me if my question is a bit vague. What I'm trying to achieve is - for each email, get the date diff for the earliest date (min) and the next date (min+1). If there is another order date, then I want to calculate diff between (min+1) and (min+2), and so on. With this I'll have a true interval between orders for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do, using `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(email) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(days_interval = difftime(date, lag(date), unit="days"))
```

Here's what I get:

```
        email order_no       date days_interval
1 a@stack.com       12 2014-02-13       NA days
2 a@stack.com       13 2014-03-13       28 days
3 a@stack.com       14 2014-06-13       92 days
4 b@stack.com       15 2014-05-13       NA days
5 b@stack.com       16 2014-05-20        7 days
6 b@stack.com       17 2014-07-20       61 days
```

Comment: Tried your solution but upon QA it doesn't yield the expected results. I'm seeing cases where the minimum date has an interval with is not N/A.

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't solve it. With that we are setting default to the minimum date, however we are not comparing date at position 2 to 3 and 3 to 4 and so on. That's what makes me believe a for loop is the only way to go.

Comment: The reference date is the minimum order date for that customer. The reference date will change for each order date. For each customer(email) i would like to get the date diff for the earliest date (min) and the next date (min+1). If there is another order date, then I want to calculate diff between (min+1) and (min+2), and so on. With this I'll have a true interval between orders for each customer.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but it doesn't solve my problem. I've posted an For Loop solution above. Perhaps that would be clearer. I would like to know if I can replicate that without using a For loop. The reason I say this is because it takes about an hour to run. Thanks. Not sure why i'm getting lots of down votes...